# number of parenthesis in input string

Tags: ruby

I have input string

```
'(p ( g k ) ( m ) )'
```

I want to calculate total number of nested parentheses for each 
   character

```
for example output should be for       p -> 1
                                 g and k -> 2
                                       m -> 2
```

Comment: Please, show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to find this answer. I tried to find a maximum depth of parenthesis but this is not working for me.

Comment: How come `m -> 1`? It's totally nested 2 times.

Comment: "this is not working for me" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Also, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Using hashes.

Set up:

```
valid_symbols = ('a'..'z')
counting = {'(' => 1, ')' => -1} # hash to be used for counting
counting.default = 0 # set default to zero
opened = 0 # for tracking opened parenthesys
res = {} # to store the result
```

Loop for counting:

```
str = '(p ( g k ) ( m ) )'

str.chars.each do |ch|
  opened += counting[ch]
  res[ch] = opened if valid_symbols.include? ch
end

res
#=> {"p"=>1, "g"=>2, "k"=>2, "m"=>2}
```

Yes, this is the basic idea, and can be refactored using `each_with_object` etc, etc..

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def nesting(expression)
  current_depth = 0

  expression.
    chars.
    map(&:strip).
    reject(&:empty?).
    each_with_object([]) do |character, nesting|
      if character == '('
        current_depth += 1
      elsif character == ')'
        current_depth -= 1
      else
        nesting.push [character, current_depth]
      end
    end
end

nesting '(p ( g k ) ( m ) )' # => [["p", 1], ["g", 2], ["k", 2], ["m", 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = '(p ( g k ) ( m ) )'
```

```
count = 0
str.delete(' ').gsub(/\(|\)|[^()]+/).with_object({}) do |s,h|
  case s
  when '(' then count += 1
  when ')' then count -= 1
  else          h[s] = count
  end
end
  #=> {"p"=>1, "gk"=>2, "m"=>2}
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that returns an enumerator when it has one argument and no block.<sup>1</sup>

The regular expression reads, "match a left parenthesis or (`|`) a right parentheses or one or more characters other than left and right parentheses (`[^()]+`).

This assumes that the parentheses in the string are balanced. One can test that as follows.

```
def balanced?(str)
  stack = []
  str.each_char do |s|
    case s
    when '('
      stack << s
    when ')'
      return false if stack.empty? || stack.last == ')'
      stack.pop
    end
  end
  stack.empty?
end
```

```
balanced? '(p ( g k ) ( m ) )'    #=> true
balanced? '(p () g k ) (( m ) )'  #=> true
balanced? '(p (( g k )) ( m ) )'  #=> true

balanced? '(p ( g k ) ( m )'      #=> false: 3 '(', 2 ')'
balanced? ')p ( g k ) (( m )'     #=> false: ')' at beginning
balanced? '(p ( g k ))) (( m ) )' #=> false: more ')' than '(' in '(p ( g k )))
```

<sup>1. This form of `gsub` is seldom used, possibly because it has nothing to do with character replacement; nonetheless, having a method that simply generates matches can be useful. It is similar to `String#scan`, except the return value of that method depends on whether the regular expression contains capture groups; `gsub` is not affected in that way.</sup>